# SharePoint Server Subscription Edition Upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-server

Based on the new version release of SharePoint Subscription Edition I have little confused on the update to the new version of the SharePoint from SharePoint 2013.

The Microsoft article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/new-and-improved-features-in-sharepoint-server-subscription-edition says
"Directly upgrading from versions of SharePoint earlier than SharePoint Server 2016 via database attach is not supported. SharePoint 2013, SharePoint 2010, and so on must first be upgraded to either SharePoint Server 2016 or SharePoint Server 2019 via database attach before upgrading to SharePoint Server Subscription Edition."

However, my query is do we need to update to SharePoint 2019 or as per this article https://ekhichdi.com/2021/07/21/sharepoint-server-subscription-edition-upgrade-path/ we can upgrade to Sharepoint 2016 from SharePoint 2013 and then to SharePoint Subscription Edition.

Anyone who can provide some clarity on the update path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a direct database attach upgrade from SharePoint Server 2016 *or* SharePoint Server 2019 to SharePoint Server Subscription Edition.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we can move a 2016 Database directly to the SharePoint Subscription Edition.

Not quite sure why it is possible, but my best guess is that the SP Subscription Edition is barely any different from the SP 2019 from the database perspective.